# Create class based up on abstract type

Tags: c#, oop

I have selveral classes based upon a standard abstract class and they will be loaded from a datatable (for the sample I used an array of int). The class wil be intiated by type and then load the specific details for that class. Currenlty I am doing this with a switch statement but is it possbile to do this an other way?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new[] {1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 4};
        TypeBase typeClass = null;
        foreach (var i in list)
        {
            switch (i)
            {
                case 1:
                    {
                        typeClass = new Type1();
                        break;
                    }
                case 2:
                    {
                        typeClass = new Type2();
                        break;
                    }
                case 3:
                    {
                        typeClass = new Type3();
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
        if (typeClass != null)
        {
            typeClass.LoadDetails();
        }
    }
}

public class TypeBase
{
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public virtual void LoadDetails()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Type1 : TypeBase
{
    public override void LoadDetails()
    {
        // Load type Specific details
    }
}

public class Type2 : TypeBase
{
    public override void LoadDetails()
    {
        // Load type Specific details
    }
}

public class Type3 : TypeBase
{
    public override void LoadDetails()
    {
        // Load type Specific details
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use reflection to try to resolve the type name: `var type = Type.GetType("typename")` and use `Activator.CreateInstance(type)` to create an instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several solutions.

**1. Create types with reflection**

This solution has already been given by Nair. Since I expect your types will not be called `Type1`, `Type2`, etc. I assume this will not work for you.

**2. Store types in a dictionaries with types**

Create a dictionary which will replace your switch/case. It contains the types you need to create:

```
Dictionary<int, Type> types = new Dictionary<int, Type>
{
    {1, typeof(Type1)},
    {2, typeof(Type2)},
    {3, typeof(Type3)}
};
```

use this to create your types:

```
Type type;
if (types.TryGetValue(i, out type))
{
    TypeBase typeClass = (TypeBase)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    typeClass.LoadDetails();
}
```

This solution is faster than solution #1, since only one "reflection" operation is used.

**3. Store types in a dictionaries with factory methods**

Create a dictionary which will replace your switch/case. It will contain factory methods:

```
Dictionary<int, Func<TypeBase>> factories = new Dictionary<int, Func<TypeBase>>
{
    {1, () => new Type1()},
    {2, () => new Type2()},
    {3, () => new Type3()}
};
```

use this to create your types:

```
Func<TypeBase> factory;
if (factories.TryGetValue(i, out factory))
{
    TypeBase typeClass = factory();
    typeClass.LoadDetails();
}
```

This solution is faster than solution #2, since there is not reflection used.

**4. Store types in a dictionaries with instances**

Create a dictionary which will replace your switch/case. It will contain instances of your types. This solution will only work if these instances are immutable and will not change state during calls.

```
Dictionary<int, TypeBase> typeClasses = new Dictionary<int, TypeBase>
{
    {1, new Type1()},
    {2, new Type2()},
    {3, new Type3()}
};
```

use this to create your types:

```
TypeBase typeClass;
if (baseClasses.TryGetValue(i, out baseClass))
{
    typeClass.LoadDetails();  
}
```

This solution is faster than solution #3, since no instances are created with every call.

**Some side notes**

- Why not use an interface, with one member `LoadDetails`? In your example member `Type` is never used.
- Why not make `TypeBase.LoadDetails` an abstract method?
- If your `keys` are always of type `Int32` and are in a continuous range, you could consider using a `List<T>` or even an array, which will be faster than a dictionary.

Comment: Will take a look and create an implementation using your sugestion look very intresting.. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should follow factory method to such requirement. Else, if you are happy to follow **conventions** for your subclass then a cheap trick would be something like below.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Remoting;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list = new[] {1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 4};
            TypeBase typeClass = null;
            foreach (var i in list)
            {
                ObjectHandle handle = Activator.CreateInstanceFrom("ConsoleApplication1", string.Format("{0}{1}", "Type", i));//Program- Name of the assembl
                var typeBase = (TypeBase) handle.Unwrap();
                typeBase.Type = i;
                typeClass.LoadDetails();
            }
        }
    }

    public class TypeBase
    {
        public int Type { get; set; }

        public virtual void LoadDetails()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class Type1 : TypeBase
    {
        public override void LoadDetails()
        {
            // Load type Specific details
        }
    }
}
```

**Note :** *I personally won't follow such approach and would more pleased with factory methods or fair number of switches. This is just to flash a possibility only. Please test and amend accordingly (if decide to follow)*

Comment: can you please explain a bit more regarding your statement: Ideally, you should follow factory method to such requirement

Comment: Factory method is a design pattern which is ideal in this case. You can read more about it [here](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternFactory.aspx#_self2). Don't limit your self try searching more factory method implementation. The benefit it that, it give you more statically typed language feature with no room for run time exceptions. This is why I prefer factory over my above draft.